# Cursor not going into context Menu options

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, mouseenter, mouseleave

I am having issues in mouseleave and mouseenter . I have an image on which when i take my mouse,it shows me the context menu . My problem is I am unable to take my mouse to enter inside the context menu so that i can select options of it.The moment i leave my mouse from image ,the context menu goes off.I want a code in which when i take my mouse over image and the context menu shows ,the context menu does not goes away the moment i try to take my mouse inside the context menu .

Here is my code :-

```
  var boolMouseEnter = false;
function ShowMenuItemsOnMouseEnter() {

$("img.showActionMenu").on('mouseenter', function (e) {

    var itemId = $(this).closest("li").attr("id");

    $('#' + itemId).trigger({ type: 'mousedown', button: 2 }).
        trigger({ type: 'mouseup', pageX: e.pageX-5, pageY: e.pageY-10 });
});

boolMouseEnter = $("#ulPackage,#ulRemoveAll,#ulRemove,#ulSort").is('mouseenter');


$("img.showActionMenu").on('mouseleave', function (e) {
    if (!boolMouseEnter) {

        $(document).trigger('click');
    }
});
}
```

ulPackage,ulRemove,ulRemoveAll,ulSort are all the "ul" ids of the context menus .

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: have you checked if `boolMouseEnter` has the expected value when `mouseenter` is triggered? try `console.log(boolMouseEnter);` after the statement that gives it its value and check your console for what it'll print out.

Comment: Better provide your HTML structure too.. ^^